# Grand Audio Engineering/Mixing and Mastering Course?

Tags: audio-recording, mixing, audio, mastering, guitar

Does anyone know courses or playlist(s) that shows how to get into the world of mixing, mastering and recording in a progressive manner?

I'm a complete newbie and would like to learn but I don't know the basis.

I would like, for example, to enhance my mixes and get the best loudness/quality ratio out of them.

Free courses would be great, but I'm also searching for paid-courses
(whatever may be the medium : books, videos, ...).

Any links or redirections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern Recording Techniques is a good starter book! Would recommend going through it!